# Flex: How to create a color Glow filter with duration

Tags: apache-flex, colors, filter, effect

I need to highlight a button's border, so I have created a glow filter like this:

```
<s:GlowFilter id="GlowFilter1"
  color="0xD9D919"
   blurX="30" blurY="40"
  alpha="1"
 />
```

The problem is that I don't know to remove the effect. The effect remains in the opction as it was highlighted.
Thus, I'd like to set a duration, or something that removes the effect I create.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

According to [adobe live docs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=Filtering_Visual_Objects_05.html).

> **Removing filters from a display object**
>
> Removing all filters from a display
>   object is as simple as assigning a
>   null value to the filters property:
>
> myDisplayObject.filters = null;

So if you want, you can set filter to the null after some time using [Timer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Timer.html), or put this in the event (e.g. MouseOut)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't still know how to set the duration of the filter. For a fade effect I can do that...

Comment: @manel as i understand you use mostly mxml and not as3, so you should try answer from Florian F

Answer (score 1):

IF you use Flex 3, use the AnimateProperty class.

There is an example in the [doc](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/effects/AnimateProperty.html#includeExamplesSummary)

Answer (score 1):

I can't say I'm a fan for Flex's filters/animations.  They seems overly cluttered to me.  I personally use [TweenMax](http://www.greensock.com/tweenmax/) because it's fast and easy to use.  In this case, if you wanted to create a glow filter, you'd do this:

```
import com.greensock.*; 
import com.greensock.easing.*;
import com.greensock.plugins.*;

// First you need to 'activate' the plugin.  Only need to do this once on app startup.
TweenPlugin.activate([GlowFilterPlugin]);

// Fade in glow
TweenMax.to(yourComponent, 1, {glowFilter:{color:0x91e600, alpha:1, blurX:30, blurY:30}});

// Fade out glow
TweenMax.to(yourComponent, 1, {glowFilter:{alpha:0, remove:true}});
```

Easy huh? :)

Comment: I dont see anything about the "delay" that is being asked